# Solving questions about functions that interact with power sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have two questions I'm working through:

> Let ℘(S) be the set of all subsets of set S, and let T be the set of
>   all functions from S to {0,1}. Show that ℘(S) and T have the same
>   cardinality.

I'm a little confused as to how I'm supposed to solve this without knowing the contents of set S, but if it was given to me I have to believe the answer doesn't require knowing those details. Also, when the question says "T is the set of all functions from S to {0,1}" that does that mean it includes functions that are not onto (so every element in S would return 1, for example?) and inverse functions? (or would that be disqualified as the functions have to go from S to {0,1}?

The second question says:

> Let S be a set and let ℘(S) be the set of all subsets of S.
>   Show that S is “smaller than” ℘(S) in the sense that there
>   is a one-to-one function from S to ℘(S) but there is no
>   onto function from ℘(S) to S.

I feel like the answer to this is obvious because if there was a function from S to ℘(S), there would always been at least the empty set in addition to the elements of the set, meaning it and possibly other elements would excluded as possible outputs from the function. Is that correct?

Comment: **Hint for the first part:** For each set $A\in\mathfrak{p}(S)$ associate with it a function $f$ where $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\notin A\\ 1&\text{if}~x\in A\end{cases}$.  Why is this useful to do?  Can we define this process of association explicitly?  What special properties does this association process have?  What does this imply about the cardinality?

Comment: As for the question of if it includes functions that are not onto, yes of course.  It does afterall say "the set of **all** functions..."  You then ask if it includes inverse functions, the answer would be no because this is only asking "all functions **from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$**"  Inverses of those functions (*if they even exist in the first place*) would be from $\{0,1\}$ to $S$, not $S$ to $\{0,1\}$ (*with the rare exceptional case where $S=\{0,1\}$, but they would have already been accounted for in the correct interpretation anyways*)

Comment: For second part, you are being asked to prove [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for these clarifying hints. Wouldn't the function always return 1, as the empty set and each subset are elements of the powerset of S? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a bit lengthy to type, so bear with me.  Here is an explicit example for part 1:

Let $S=\{a,b,c\}$ and $T=\{f~:~S\to \{0,1\}\}$ be the set of all functions from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$.  Then $T$ is equal to the following:

$$T=\left\{\begin{array}{}\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,0)\},\color{red}{\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,1)\}},\{(a,0),(b,1),(c,0)\},\\\{(a,0),(b,1),(c,1)\},\{(a,1),(b,0),(c,0)\},\{(a,1),(b,0),(c,1)\},\\\color{blue}{\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,0)\}},\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)\}\end{array}\right\}$$

(*Not enough space to write them all side by side, so I had to use multiple lines.  No meaning is applied to which line they are on.*)

This is writing each function in the form of a subset of the cartesian product between the domain and the codomain.  That is to say,

the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ function is the function $f~:~S\to\{0,1\}$ defined as $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x=a~\text{or}~x=b\\1&\text{if}~x=c\end{cases}$

while the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ function is the function $g~:~S\to\{0,1\}$ defined as $g(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x=c\\1&\text{if}~x=a~\text{or}~x=b\end{cases}$

My hint above is to think of the power set in a similar fashion.  Notice that we can write the power set for this example too.

$$\mathcal{P}(S) = \left\{\begin{array}{}\emptyset,\color{red}{\{c\}},\{b\},\\\{b,c\},\{a\},\{a,c\},\\\color{blue}{\{a,b\}},\{a,b,c\}\end{array}\right\}$$

Notice how the red function $\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,1)\}$ is related to the element of the power set $\{c\}$.  Notice how the blue function $\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,0)\}$ is related to the blue element of the power set $\{a,b\}$.

---

Commonly to prove two sets are of the same cardinality, we show that there exists a bijection between them.  In this case, we want to show that there exists a bijective function from the set of functions $T=\{f~:~S\to\{0,1\}\}$ to the power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$.  Yes, we are taking functions of functions.  That is okay.  For us at the moment, the functions in $T$ are the inputs of the hopefully bijective function we can find between $T$ and $\mathcal{P}(S)$.

Now, look back at my original hint and look at the order I've written the explicit example above for both $T$ and $\mathcal{P}(S)$ so you can verify that at least in this case the function you should have in mind is indeed bijective.  Now what remains is to prove that it *is* bijective regardless of what set $S$ happened to be.

---

For the second part, the proof is rather elementary in the case that $S$ is finite (*by noting that $|\mathcal{P}(S)|=2^{|S|}$*), but when $S$ is countably infinite or even worse when $S$ is uncountably infinite it becomes more challenging.  I would just recommend reading the [article on Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem) on wikipedia.

Comment: I got caught up with schoolwork, so I apologize for my tardy reply - I just want to say this is hugely clarifying and helpful. Thank you for taking the time to write this.